# Architecture in an Android multimodule project

Tags: android, architecture, dagger-2, multi-module

I'm building a small app with different modules:

- `core` is the one holding lots of shared code such as network, etc. This module has no dependencies with any other module.
- `app` is the entry point of my application and as far as I know, it should depend on `core` and the feature modules via `implementation project(:core)`, `implementation project(:features:drinks)`, etc.
- `drinks`, `categories` and `ingredients` are the non-dynamic feature modules. As far as I know, these feature modules should only depend on the `core` module via `implementation project(:core)`

Is this implementation architecturally well defined and implemented?
I've been digging into multimodule projects, always looking at the [plaid app](https://github.com/android/plaid) but when implementing it in my project, it's becoming more and more complicated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to look here: https://github.com/google/iosched . They have a lot of modules and the app is also for tv. Here more about the project: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/google-i-o-2018-app-architecture-and-testing-f546e37fc7eb